# Error in statically linking libSDL

Tags: compiling, g++, sdl

I am trying to statically link libsdl on a test I wrote.
What I did is:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wl,-Bstatic  $(sdl-config --static-libs) -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

which gave me the error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libSDL.a(SDL_x11gl.o): In function`X11_GL_LoadLibrary':
(.text+0x703): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse-simple
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added the line "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" (the directory where libasound.so resides), but nothing changed. Any solution?